# Is it possible to shutdown or restart a Logitech Revue without pulling the power cord?

Tags: 3.1-honeycomb, google-tv, logitech-revue

My Revue (Android 3.1) was acting balky, so I wanted to restart it.  I spent several minutes looking through menus, but didn't find an option to shut down or restart the OS.   I ended up pulling the power cord, but it seemed a bit harsh.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Google's support page](http://support.google.com/googletv/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1679450) provides this option:

> **To Reboot your Google TV:**
>
> To reboot your Sony TV or Bluray player or your Logitech Revue, press
>   Control + Alt + Backspace on your controller.

If you had `adb` connected you could also try `adb reboot`, which works on other devices.